# Can't see list of screen resolutions anymore when Option-Clicking the Scaled button on macOS 10.15.4

Tags: display, resolution, preferences

I used to be able to Option-Click on Scaled button in the Display Preferences window to see a full list of resolutions, e.g., 1920x1080, 1280x720, etc.

But recently (started with 10.15.4, I think) this action does NOT reveal resolutions.  Instead, it gives me an option to select the different refresh rates.

How can I get the full list of resolutions again?

[image: Display Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was restored after the latest macOS update (10.15.6).  Maybe it was accidentally disabled in the previous version.